# GIMP mapping matrix text is horizontal but should be rotated to vertical - bug, or can I fix this?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gimp

Using 18.04, GNOME 3.28.2 on Xorg, GIMP 2.8.22.

In case anyone else has even seen this - the text on the mapping matrix for brush dynamics is not properly rotated to the vertical orientation. Any idea how to fix this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you don't get an answer here after a few days, you can repost your question in Stack Exchange Graphic Design: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe check that this is true with all themes, and report on https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues